# using curl to download files with padded zeroes

Tags: bash, curl

Hi I have multiple files example
01.pdf
02.pdf
etc

In a bash script I created a for loop and use curl, however it tries to download
1.pdf
2.pdf
etc

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf` for padding filenames:

```
urlbase='http://myhost.com/path/files'
for i in {1..10}; do
    fname=$(printf "%02d.pdf\n" $i)
    curl -o $fname "$urlbase/$fname"
done
```

Comment: I understand that but how would I implement that with the curl command?

Comment: You can also use `printf -v fname` to assign value to the variable.